# Strange IE vs Firefox Javascript animation speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, timer, internet-explorer-9

I have the following function that ties into a bunch of different plugin settings, allowing you to configure the handles, speed, and angles for rotating objects. Everything runs crystal clear and really nice in IE9, but firefox is jerky.

```
// 1. FUNCTION ROTATE ANIMATIONS IN
function rotate_on(degree, index){
clearTimeout(rotateofftimer);   /* CLEAR ANIMATION OUT TIMER */

// A. APPLY THE CROSS-BROWSER CSS FOR ROTATIONS
if((ievers==6)||(ievers==7)||(ievers==8)){ if(ievers==8){ /* IE 8 CODE */ current_obj.css({/* IE8 */'-ms-filter':'"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+degree+')"',/* IE<8 */'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+degree+')'});} else { /* IE 6/7 CODE */ };

} else { /* NON IE */ 
current_obj.css({/* W3C CSS3 standard */'transform':'translateX(0)rotate('+degree+'deg)','transform-origin':OS.rotate_handle_on_set[index],/* Firefox */'-moz-transform':'translateX(0)rotate('+degree+'deg)','-moz-transform-origin':OS.rotate_handle_on_set[index],/* Chrome, Safari, Mobile, Etc. */'-webkit-transform':'translateX(0)rotate('+degree+'deg)','-webkit-transform-origin':OS.rotate_handle_on_set[index],/* Opera */'-o-transform':'translateX(0)rotate('+degree+'deg)','-o-transform-origin':OS.rotate_handle_on_set[index],/* IE>=9 */'-ms-transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)','-ms-transform':'translateX(0)rotate('+degree+'deg)','-ms-transform-origin':OS.rotate_handle_on_set[index]});};

// B. TEST FOR REPEAT ROTATIONS - IF VALUES ARE THE SAME, REPEAT ROTATIONS
if(OS.rotate_on_set[index]==OS.rotate_off_set[index]){ 

// SAVE THE ENDING VALUE TO PICKUP ON NEXT PLAY (IF LOOPING)
OS.rotate_on_set[index]=degree;OS.rotate_off_set[index]=degree; degree++;
}else{ if(degree<OS.rotate_off_set[index]){ degree++ };};

// C. TRIGGER THE FUNCTION IN A TIMER, BASED ON USER SPEED
rotateontimer = setTimeout(function(){rotate_on(degree, index)},OS.rotate_speed_on_set[index]);};
```

The strange thing is, when I turn the speed down so that the animation is really slow, it's basically jerking through 1 frame at a time in Firefox, but IE9 seems to know how to translate that into a smooth/slow animation. Could it be something to do with the timers?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some more complete code or setup a working example using [http://jsfiddle.net/](jsFiddle)?

Comment: The plugin is really long at this point. Basically, on hover this function is called and the object (and it's index) is passed to the function. The function A: Applies the initial CSS for rotation to the current object (based on user settings pulled from a JSON object). B: Has an option for looping the rotation, and if looped just saves the current angle. C. Creates a timer which rotates the object and invokes the timer every X seconds.

Comment: Sorry, there's a ton of variables in there. Basically the function is called on mouseover (and passed a current object and it's index). The object has already been styled to the correct angle. There's a timer inside the function which calls the the function every Nseconds. The function increments the degree and applies it to the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just seems to be the way Firefox is. I have the same problem of choppy JS animations and ONLY when viewed with Firefox. Internet Explorer 9 (in standard mode plus compatibility modes "IE7" and "IE8") and Chrome both display smooth animations under all circumstances.

Trust me, we're not the only ones with this problem and to day no clear solution exists.

Comment: we are living in the stone-age when it comes to these kind of stuff. and FF is really disappointing in performance..(I'm on version 18)

Comment: for Firefox when you add translate3d(0,0,0) to your transform property it forces hardware acceleration in the browser so the animation becomes smooth .. best to have it in your stylesheet when the page loads for best performance.. http://jsfiddle.net/esAGA/16/ -